# Turn off minification in Laravel Mix production options

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, web-frontend

I'm trying to turn off minification during the production build process. This is where I'm currently at in my webpack.mix.js file. However, nothing I've tried is working so far. What is the best way to do this?

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
.options({
      minimize:false,
      uglify: {
        uglifyOptions: {
          warnings: false,
          comments: false,
          beautify: true,
          minify: false,
          minimize: false,
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            minimize: false,
          }
        }
      },
      cssnano:false,
  })
.js('src/js/app.js', 'assets/js/common.js')
.sass('src/scss/style.scss', '').options({processCssUrls: false});



if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.options({
        minimize: false,
      uglify: {
        uglifyOptions: {
          warnings: false,
          comments: false,
          beautify: false,
          minify: false,
          minimize: false,
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            minimize: false,
          }
        }
      },
      cssnano:false,
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not just build it in non-production mode? `npm run dev` instead of `npm run prod`?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?